# What does the GlusterFS server option cluster.readdir-optimize control?

Tags: linux, rhel, glusterfs, distributed-filesystem

I have been trying to optimise the small file performance of my GlusterFS storage cluster.

A number of forum threads and blog posts seem to suggest setting the `cluster.readdir-optimize` property on the volume, like:

```
$ gluster volume get test-share cluster.readdir-optimize on
```

The default for this option (as of GlusterFS v3.10) seems to be `off`, which makes me think there must be some trade-off to having this feature enabled. However, I have not been able to find anywhere any documentation explaining exactly what this option does.

I would like to understand the function of this option before I enable it in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the relevant GlusterFS git repository [commit message](https://github.com/gluster/glusterfs/commit/e404e9b81f18c0a36a5c67ebf041ac0a00ca2eb1), the `readdir-optimize` option supports the following:

> Bring in option which is supported by posix xlator
>   to filter out directory's entries from being returned.
>   DHT would now request non-first subvols to filter out
>   directory entries.

I don't fully understand how this directly improves performance in GlusterFS with respect to small files. But according to the [GlusterFS documentation](https://gluster-documentations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Developer-guide/bd-xlator/) the BD xalator performs the function of wrapping the GlusterFS block back-end and enables GlusterFS volumes to be composed of bricks which are themselves underlying logical volumes.